# Why is package not appearing in device explorer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I accidentally deleted the database file in device explorer. I thought a new database would be created, but now I can't view the package in device explorer to check if a new one has been created. Suggestions as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple

1. Uninstall the app
2. Reinstall the App.

should fix the issue since the CreateDatbase method wherever you have will be called the moment you add gets installed again.

ALso Database Inspector is not reliable so it takes some time. If you're using SQLLite Database the database won't be visible until you make the `db.makeDatabaseReadable()` method